# UInt16Array not working as expected (wrong order)

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I have some binary data in a file im reading (Hex):

```
00 00 00 18 66 74 79 70
```

I read the file and convert it to an arrayBuffer and both Uint8Array and Uint16Array.

```
const arrayBuffer = await selectedFile.arrayBuffer()
  
const uint8Array  = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
const uint16Array = new UInt16Array(arrayBuffer)
```

The content of Uint8Array is as expected:

```
   Decimal        Hex

0: 0              0
1: 0              0
2: 0              0
3: 24             18   
4: 102            66
5: 116            74
6: 121            79
7: 112            70
```

But in the uint16Array the two bytes are **flipped**.

```
   Decimal        Hex          What I expected as Hex

0: 0              0            0
1: 6144           18 00        00 18
2: 29798          74 66        66 74
3: 28793          70 79        79 70
```

Why are the two bytes flipped? What can I do to get the right order, if e.g. I need to search 0x6674.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the file (of the data format) is a different one than that of your processor.

If you care about endianness (and you do, if you read or write files meant to be used on different platforms), don't use a [`Uint16Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint16Array) that always uses the platform byte order, use a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) instead and call the [`getUint16`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getUint16) method for each index.